# Construction of the lamplighter group as wreath product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry

For groups $(G,+)$ and $(H,\cdot)$ the wreath product $G \wr H$ is the set $W = G^H \times H$ (the set of all functions times $H$, so a typical element is $(f,h)$ where $f : H \to G$ and $h \in H$) together with the composition
$$
 (f, h)(f', h') = (g, hh') 
$$
where $g$ is defined, for each $q \in H$ by
$$
 g(q) = f(q) + f'(qh).
$$
(the additive notation does not imply it to be commutative!) Now the lamp lighter group is $\mathbb Z_2 \wr \mathbb Z$. So as I see it with the above mentioned definitions for example $f(n) = n \mbox{mod} 2$ and $f'(n) = 1_{\mathbb N}$ (indicator function of the natural numbers) then
$$
 (f, 3) \mbox{ and } (f', 5)
$$
would be both elements of the lamp lighter group, and their product would be $(g, 15)$ with $g(n) = f(n) + f'(n+3)$. But as I read elsewhere, and according to a famous interpretation of this group, as functions are just those allowed for which $\{ n : f(n) = 1 \}$ is finite. But where does this come from, to quote a book:

> ... consider the lamplighter group $\mathbb Z_2 \wr \mathbb Z$, the wreath product of $\mathbb Z_2$ with $\mathbb Z$. One can define this group by using as a state space $X$ the configuration space of a doubly infinite sequence of lamps (indexed by the inegers), with each lamp being either "on" or "off", and with at most finitely many of the lamps begin "on", together with the position of a lamplighter, located at one of the lamps; more formally, we have $X := (\mathbb Z)^{\mathbb Z}_0 \times \mathbb Z$, where $(\mathbb Z)^{\mathbb Z}_0$ is the space of compactly supported sequences from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z_2$. The lamplighter has the ability to toggle the lamp on and off at his or her current location, and also the ability to move left or right...

On wikipedia there is a similar interpretation. But where does this interpretation and also the requirement that just functions whose roots are a cofinite set comes from? I don't see it in the definition of the wreath product, or have I misunderstood something? Hope someone could clarify..

Comment: Your definition of the wreath product uses the symbol $+$, so you are probably assuming everything is abelian (and written additively) from the get-go.

Comment: no, it is from a book and the author states using the additive notation there just "to provide a more transparent notation, but it is not meant to suggest that $H$ is commutative", forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You speak of "the" definition of wreath product and mention Wikipedia $-$ but there is more than one type of wreath product: there are *restricted* and *unrestricted* wreath products (as you will see defined on the Wikipedia page for wreath product).

Comment: I referred to the wikipedia entry on the lightlamper group. But I already saw the wiki entry on wreath product, but it does not helps me much, I tried to understand it by a concrete example, here the lightlamper group. Do you know how exactly it arises as a wreath product?

Comment: @Stefan I am not sure I understand your question. It is the restricted wreath product $C_2\wr\Bbb Z$. You already understand this though don't you? Or don't you? The examples of functions you give are in the unrestricted wreath product, not the restricted one...

Comment: Ah, okay thank you. Yes, I am using a different wreath product, but my book does not make this distinction. btw do you know any resources where these different wreath products are explained, would be nice if sharing!

Comment: Yes, the difference is explained on Wikipedia! Do you know the difference between direct product and direct sum of groups? Also: the quote you give *does* make it clear that the lamplighter group is a restricted product, although the definition of wreath product you give is that of an unrestricted one. Are these from two different texts? If so, then no wonder!

Comment: yes, they are from two different text. Yes I understand the difference, but btw whats the difference between direct product and direct sum for groups, is it just that for direct sum just finitely many $\ne 0$ and for direct product no restriction, then these products coincide in the finite case?

Comment: Yes, that is the difference between direct product and direct sum of groups. (That you're asking suggests you *didn't* previously understand!)